# How to change JSON key:value pair using UPDATE query?

Tags: node.js, json, sqlite, sql-update

I have JSON object in an SQLite table column and need to change the value of a key:

| column |
| --- |
| {"foo": "bar", "bar2": "foo2"} |

I want to get:

| column |
| --- |
| {"foo": "changed_value", "bar2": "foo2"} |

Can I do it with an SQL query? If not, how to do it in Node.js with a minimal amount of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the function [`json_replace()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jrepl):

```
UPDATE tablename
SET col = json_replace(col, '$.foo', 'changed_value')
```

Change `tablename` and `col` to the names of the table and the column that you have.

Probably you also need a `WHERE` clause for the actual row(s) that you want to update.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/zhaqJ54M).

Comment: Thanks for a link to the sqlite docs! There I found the json_set function that adds a new key:value pair if it doesn't exist